# To check if list of string and lists is empty

Tags: python

how to check if this list is empty?

```
l = ['',['']]
```

I tried solutions from how to find if nested lists are empty. but none of them worked.

```
def isListEmpty(inList):
    if isinstance(inList, list): # Is a list
         return all( map(isListEmpty, inList) )
    return False # Not a list
```

Comment: Do you have to check if the nested list is empty?

Comment: Check if its [length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) is zero?

Comment: @Austin That string is actually not empty.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm pretty sure OP means it as empty string though there is a space like you say.

Comment: Its empty string. I used the space to make it clear

Comment: why don't you [flatten the nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/5858851) and check each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the list is falsy/empty first before recursively checking the list items. You can also avoid explicitly returning `True` or `False` by using the `and` and `or` operators:

```
def isListEmpty(inList):
    return inList == '' or isinstance(inList, list) and (not inList or all(map(isListEmpty, inList)))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/AccurateSmallOutcome

Comment: returns false for everything

Comment: It returns `True` for `[[[]]]` for example.

Comment: true but that is not the list I want to check for

Comment: So you consider a list with an empty string empty?

Comment: In that case I've updated my answer accordingly. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

For lists that actually are empty, the function should simply return True.

```
def isListEmpty(inList):
    if isinstance(inList, list): # Is a list
        if len(inList) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return all(map(isListEmpty, inList))
    return False # Not a list
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide a sample list that fails?

Comment: I added it in question itself

Comment: That list contains a string, and your sample code explicitly returns non-empty for any data type that is not a list.  If that is not your desired behavior, you chould make that clear.

Comment: yes its a list of (empty string and list of empty string)

Answer (score 0):

`l` is not empty in fact. But in this case this code should work:

```
l = ['',['']]
def isListEmpty(inList):
    for char in inList:   
        if char == '' or ['']:
            return True
        else:
            return False
            break

print(isListEmpty(l))
```

Comment: What about for deeper lists like `['',['',['']]]` ? That is why other people have taken a recursive approach, because it can be infinitely deep

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple recursive approach with `any`. Using `any` would make sure that the recursively search ends as soon as a non empty item is found

```
>>> def is_non_empty_list (l):
...     return any(is_non_empty_list(e) if isinstance(e, list) else e for e in l)
... 
>>> def is_empty_list (l):
...     return not is_non_empty_list(l)
... 
>>> is_empty_list(['', ['']])
True
>>> is_empty_list(['', ['a']])
False
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
l = [' ',[ ]]
def isListEmpty(thisList):
  for el in thisList:
    if (len(el)==0 and type(el)==list):
      print('empty') # Or whatever you want to do if you encounter an empty list

isListEmpty(l)
```

If you face any problems comment below